# 0.1 + 0.7 != 0.8

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, boolean-expression

Why in some programming languages the expression in title evaluates to true? I've tried it in php, ruby and python.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)  And about a hundred other questions.

Comment: The accepted answer to that one is marvelous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken/588014#588014

Comment: It evaluates to true because it is true (when 0.1, etc are floating-point literals).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please read [`What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](http://floating-point-gui.de/) .

Answer (score 2):

```
double TOLERANCE < 1.0E-10;
if(fabs(0.1+0.7-0.8)< TOLERANCE)
{
    std::cout << "0.1 + 0.7 == 0.8" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "0.1 + 0.7 != 0.8" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of internal interpretation of floating-point numbers, they do not exactly equal to what you have wrote.